# ODS HTML Email output - my cells are all squeezed, how to expand to full length of column name?

Tags: sql, sas

i have a macro to trigger an email with table embedded. now when the table is displayed, the cells are all compressed. I have already done a outputwidth to 100% but apparently it's not working in both email and result tab. can anyone advise? is there any syntax that makes the columns display fully expanded to display either the column name or data?

```
%macro qc_email(trade_week, data_dump,  email_add);
ods _all_ close;
filename mymail email &email_add. subject="Missing Customers for Week 
&trade_week" content_type='text/html';
ods html file=mymail;
proc print style=table {OUTPUTWIDTH=100%} data=&data_dump;
run;
ods html close;
%mend qc_email;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I could not replicate the issue as nothing was wrapped when I try to run the same code in 9.4, but you should be able to control HTML output with styles. So if you do not want words to break, you may want to use CSS property white-space:nowrap which should be sufficient for that task. If it does not help you can also try adding overflow-wrap:normal.

```
proc template;
    define style styles.nowrap;
        parent=styles.default;
        style Data from Data / 
           htmlStyle="white-space:nowrap;overflow-wrap:normal;";
        style Header from Header /
           htmlStyle="white-space:nowrap;overflow-wrap:normal;";        
    end;
run;
```

and then reference the style from ods html statement as:

```
ods html file=mymail style=styles.nowrap;
```

Comment: hi, i just tried. other than the colour of the table/border changing to blue, the column still get squashed up.

Comment: Well, that was not supposed to happen :) Can you save your file as HTML and check what is the contents of data and header CSS objects?
It should look like .data { background-color: #D3D3D3; ...... } and the same for header.

I'm also wondering if changing ODS HTML to ODS HTML5 will change anything in your situation. I'm not sure that the styles I showed above will work with HTML5, but it may fix the issue somehow else.